# Model structure on the category of dgLie algebras

Tags: reference-request, model-categories, dg-lie-algebras

Where can I find a good, explicit description the model category structure on the category of differential graded Lie algebras given in the [nCatLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+dg-Lie+algebras), and the proof of the fact that it is really one?

I tried looking up appendix B of Quillen's [RHT](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~konter/gtrs/rational.pdf), but I didn't find what I wanted.

Comment: For example, Hinich, “Homological algebra of homotopy algebras”.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks. You can put your comment with an hyperlink in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Dmitri Pavlov in a comment, this was done in the article [Homological algebra of homotopy algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9702015) by V. Hinich. In fact the case treated there is the more general one of algebras over an operad.